# How to stop casting immediately on Android?

Tags: android, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I need to stop casting after the user enabled it inside my app.
The app listened to `MediaRouter.Callback` as below:

```
 private val mediaRouterCallback = object : MediaRouter.Callback() {
    override fun onRouteChanged(router: MediaRouter?, route: RouteInfo?) {
        super.onRouteChanged(router, route)
       
        // notify observers that casting occurs
    }
}
```

Now, in the observers, I need to **stop casting immediately** when the user should not use casting inside the app.

Let's suppose the code below is inside a Fragment and observes the casting event, so what would be the implementation code for `stopCasting()` method, for example:

```
when (event) {
    PreventCasting -> {
         stopCasting()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop casting you only need to use `castContext?.sessionManager?.endCurrentSession(true)`